# Is there any more efficient algorithm to find all intervals containing a specific time?

Tags: algorithm

Let's assume that I have a sorted list of `start_time` and `duration` pair which is sorted based on `start_time`. I need to find all entries that cover a specific time. For example:

```
index start_time        duration
--------------------------------
1     2                   7
2     4                   1
3     5                   3
4     7                   4

find(6) = {1,3}
```

I can do this easily in `O(n)` by simply traversing through list. But I wonder if there is any algorithm or data structure to improve this time. Any idea?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_tree

Comment: @Paul Thanks, I will check it.

Comment: you can use binary search. if your entry exactly matches a start_time return entry_index - 1, entry_index + 1 else keep moving such that mid - 1 < mid < mid + 1

Comment: Any entry prior to start may cover the time, so it is still O(n) even after binary search to find last earlier start.

Comment: @Paul I have not read interval tree completely, but since we need to find **all** possible intervals, the running time of `O(log(n) +m)` will become `O(n)` in the worst case, isn't it?

Comment: Yes, but that is the best you can do in the case where all intervals overlap and you need to output all of them. You can't have a running time that grows slower than the size of the output.

Comment: Most queries probably only return a handful of intervals, so `m` is usually small, but in the worst case `m = n`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

No. I write the array as (start_time, end_time) it's easier for us to reason that way.
Consider [(1,100),(2,99),(3,96),(4,102)], with point 101.

What I did here is choose the lower bound of the target interval to be obviously included by the lower bounds of your list, so the fact that they are sorted is of little use here, you will know, in O(log(n)) if you wish, that all interval starts are valid. Interval ends are the question to be answered, and it is equivalent to the question of being given a number (101), an unsorted array (the interval end times, or alternatively the durations which are an implicit statement of the end-times), find all numbers that are larger than this number, which is only doable in O(n). An interval tree as suggested by one of the comments would help you in queries, but for a single point, you must read all the intervals at least once.

Comment: I think your logic is incorrect. Because the main problem is not `end_time`. you cannot even correctly select `start_time` with lower bound. My question was about a single time point like 50, but same problem is for searching intervals. Assume your search interval is (50, 60). it can be found in all those ` [(1,100),(2,99),(3,96),(4,102)]` ranges. Here answer is not a single interval, it is all 4 intervals.

Comment: sorry i thought you were doing intervals. I misread. I will accordingly update.